# Changing fractional values in a column in Python( e.g from 4.1/5 -> 4.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am fairly new to python hopefully I am able to explain the problem.

I have a DataFrame where the values in a column are present as 4.1/5 , 3.9/5 , 2/5 .

I want to convert these values to show just the numerators i.e 4.1 , 3.9 , 2.

`rating= df['rate'].dropna()`

```
0         4.1/5
1         4.1/5
2         3.8/5
3         3.7/5
4         3.8/5
          ...  
51709    3.7 /5
51711    2.5 /5
51712    3.6 /5
51715    4.3 /5
51716    3.4 /5
Name: rate, Length: 51717, dtype: object
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use:

```
df['rate'] = df['rate'].str.split('/', expand=True)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I further used `rating = pd.to_numeric(df['rate'].dropna() , errors='coerce')` for ploting

Answer (score 0):

I assume the items are strings. You can remove the slash and "denominator" using `str.replace`:

```
df['rate'] = df['rate'].str.replace(r' */.*', '', regex=True)
```

If you further want to convert to float:

```
df['rate'] = df['rate'].str.replace(r' */.*', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert them into string if they are not. Then chop off the last 3 chars then convert back into float

```
df.rate.apply(lambda x: float(str(x)[:-3]) )
```

Comment: How do you know that there will always be 3 characters to remove? Also `apply` is not efficient for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split on `/` and take first part of split:

```
ratings = df['rate'].str.split('/').str[0].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work explicitly and gave the error -  _could not convert string to float: 'NEW'_.  However I was able to go around it using :                                                                   `df['rate'] = df['rate'].str.split('/', expand=True)[0] 
rating = pd.to_numeric(df['rate'].dropna() , errors='coerce')`

Comment: @Arindam well that's because there was the string `NEW` in `df['rate']` that you didn't disclose in your question. And, `rating = pd.to_numeric(df['rate'].str.split('/').str[0], errors='coerce').dropna()` should give your desired outcome.